# Getting a page to scroll up and down using jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I currently have this code that is linked to images of a left and right button that make the page scroll left and right.

```
    jQuery('.go-right').click(function() {
    jQuery(".thumbs").stop().animate({left:'-'+(parseFloat(jQuery(".thumbs").width())-parseFloat(jQuery(window).width()))+'px'},{queue:false,duration:300});
    jQuery(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.20);
    jQuery('.go-left').show();
    jQuery('img.go-left').fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
    return false;
});
jQuery('.go-left').click(function() {
    jQuery(".thumbs").stop().animate({left:'0'},{queue:false,duration:300});
    jQuery(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.20);
    jQuery('.go-right').show();
    jQuery('img.go-right').fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
    return false;
});
```

And I want to use something similar to link to an up and down button but I can't get it to work.. this is what I have so far.. any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

My logic for 'go-down' seems to make my page go up.. (but doesn't fade in and out when clicked) and my 'go-up' does nothing (put still fades in and out when clicked).

```
    jQuery('.go-down').click(function() {
    jQuery(".thumbs").stop().animate({scrollTop: $elem.height()}, 800);
    jQuery(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.20);
    jQuery('.go-down').show();
    jQuery('img.go-down').fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
    return false;
    });

jQuery('.go-up').click(function() {
    jQuery(".thumbs").stop().animate({scrollTop: 0});
    jQuery(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.20);
    jQuery('.go-up').show();
    jQuery('img.go-up').fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
    return false;
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure if is what you want, but see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yd64x/), could you help